# Derived column - concatenate field from duplicate IDs

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I receive a large monthly csv with records I have to ingest into a database table.
The records look something like this:

Input
[image: Input]

[image: OutPut]

How can I do this? Is Derived Column the best way to do this?

Comment: the best thing is not to do this. i guess it is ok for presentation layer. but i would advise against storing data in a table like this.

Comment: if there is meaning to the partners and there are always 2 then store them in 2 columns. like the first one is the seller and the 2nd is the buyer. but to save them in the same column isn't the solution.